# Regex to only keep hashtags

Tags: regex, hashtag, regexp-replace

Using regex I am trying to only keep hashtags in the text. I am trying to match everything else and replace with not significant group. But maybe there is a smarter approach.

Example text:

```
This is a #text, which is #full of #hashtags.
Well, this is not #easy to
#extract #them. 
I think I #start to lose: #hope.
```

My best try: `([\s\.\,]|^)[^#]\w+([\s\.\,]*?|$)`

Replacing with `$2` returns

```
 a #text #full #hashtags #easy
#extract #them. I #start: #hope.
```

The expected result should have 4 rows, as in the example. Spaces can also stay.
Ideal desired result:

```
#text #full #hashtags
#easy
#extract #them
#start #hope
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/438VbF/1)

Comment: Without exact details about the regex engine and programming language, it is not quite easy to provide a straightforward answer. Try `(#\w+)|(?:(?!#\w).)+` to replace with `"$1 "` (with no `"`). If you are working in Notepad++, it will become much simpler.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/khzqrD/1

Comment: With PCRE2, you could use [conditional replacement](https://regex101.com/r/438VbF/2). Same can be done with Boost, but the replacement will be `(?{1}$1\n:)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind keeping the leading spaces (which you might trim afterwards), you could use group 1 in the replacement and match:

```
.*?(\s*#\w+)|.+
```

The pattern matches:

- `.*?` Match any chat except a newline as least as possible
- `(\s*#\w+)` Capture in group 1 matching optional whitespace chars, then `#` and 1+ word chars
- `|` Or
- `.+` Match 1+ times any char except a newline

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qTh6ja/1)

If you don't want to keep the leading spaces but don't mind trailing spaces, you can use group 1 followed by a space in the replacement and match:

```
.*?(#\w+)|.+
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/w7w8Cv/1)

Answer (score 1):

This one is nice and easy to understand, and has the same replacement as yours:

```
[^#]*?(#\w+)
```

It just eats as many characters as it can until it hits a `#`, then captures all the normal word characters into the group, and repeats.

[Try it online!](https://regex101.com/r/438VbF/3)